# Entity framework parent child class set value make error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx

I have class Product was generated by EDMX,

```
class Product{
 public Category cate;
}
```

I creat Product1 extend Product, manually.
When I set the category value

```
 Product1 p = new Product();
    p.cate = c1;
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll Additional information: Object
>   mapping could not be found for Type with identity 'Product1'

Comment: `Product1` isn't part of the Entity Framework model. `Product` is.

Comment: You cannot use inheritance this way, EDMX will not let you play with anything apart from that is defined in the model. You have to reconsider your design.